# Why does this while loop end at -1?

Tags: c

This is an exercise of my school and I'm trying to understand why the while loop ends at `-1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0xfe - 067;

    while (a > 9 ? !!!0 : !!(a + 1, a -= 2, --a))
    {
        printf("%d \n", a);
        if (a + 2 > 0x11) //(17)
        {
            a = -3;
            continue;
        }
        a += 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know is not a realistic example but my school put this exercise in the exam. I see that when `a=-1` at top value `a+=4` sets `a` to `3` and the loop stops.

Comment: Honestly you should use a debugger and step through your code one line at the time. Or you can do it old school style and write down the values after each iteration

Comment: Shouldn't you ask your teacher to explain it then? The while uses a ternary operator with a lot of bloat (probably to confuse you). Besides that, @drum is right, step through it one by one to see what happens and why.

Comment: What school is giving students such crap? Does the teacher have complexes and wants to show how "hacky" he is?

Comment: If the students' programming level is "beginner", and there's an assessment that couldn't be scored maximum without solving this problem, then the teacher is an idiot (and maybe teaching isn't their best career path). *BTW*: you can show them this comment. If it's just for fun (each coming with a solution and a debate is started), then it's OK. If on the other hand you want to show off in front of your colleagues, or this exact exercise will be part of the future test and you want to know the result upfront (cheating), this ain't very honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the last loop iteration, a is 3.

```
while (a>9 ? !!!0:!!( a+1,a-=2,--a))
```

`a>9` is false, so the right-hand side of the ternary expression is used:

```
!!( a+1,a-=2,--a)
```

The expression inside the parentheses is evaluated first:

```
a+1,a-=2,--a
```

When you have several expressions separated by commas, each expression is evaluated in order left-to-right. The value of each expression is then discarded, except for the rightmost expression.

So the expressions are evaluated in this order:

`a+1` is 4.  This value is discarded.  `a` is still 3.

`a-=2` is 1.  This value is discarded.  However the `-=` operator does modify the value of a, so a is now 1.

`--a` is 0.  This is the rightmost expression, so its value is kept.

`!!` is then applied to 0.  The first `!` flips the 0 to 1, and then the second `!` flips the 1 back to 0.

So the final value is 0, and the loop exits.

Comment: Re "*ternary expression*", "Conditional operator", that is.

Comment: the program's output is `199
-6
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
` so you should explain that after printing `-1`, the `if` test expression is false, hence `a += 4` is evaluated, giving `a` the value `3` for the test in the `while` loop.

Comment: @chqrlie They already said that they knew the last loop value of `a` was 3.  So I started my answer from there.

Comment: I've figure it out yesterday and then check the answer and i was considering a+3 like a=3. Next time just doing this in the morning